# Search relationship data laravel scout elasticsearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

While using scout elastic search i need to use the same index for a model and their related fields as well.
I created the index, but multiple model is not mapped with the same index. Also for same model related fields are not migrated.

Eg.

My index is lead_index

Model A has a Model B

Model A is a searchable model

All fields of Model A and Model B are mentioned in model A

Running model update with index is fine with Model A but throws error when trying to map with model B as multiple model cannot be mapped with same index.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to add field of related model to the same index via laravel scout elastic search

Comment: Laravel scout doesn't have Elasticsearch engine. What package do you use?

Comment: I am using this package https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Scout has `raw` method so you can map results on your own

```
$modelB = new SearchResults(ModelA::search('zonga')->raw())->first()->modelB;
```

If you need to search among multiple models consider using an engine with multi-model searching feature. https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch#search-amongst-multiple-models

```
Mixed::search('title:Barcelona or to:Barcelona')
    within(implode(',', [
        (new Ticket())->searchableAs(),
        (new Book())->searchableAs(),
    ]))
->get();
```

Comment: I am using laravel 5.8 and  this packag https://github.com/ErickTamayo/laravel-scout-elastic . How i can search from multiple models? 

Package you highlighted doesn't work with Laravel 5.8

Comment: Did you try `3.x` version? https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch/tree/3.x